# Obtaining nav_msgs/Odometry from a laser_scan (eg. with laser_scan_matcher)

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, laser-scan-matcher, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to obtain `nav_msgs/Odometry` message expressed in `base_link` basing on laser measurements with any existing package? I'd like to feed it to `base_local_planner` in the future, and laser measurements is all I have to estimate odometry.

E.g. the `laser_scan_matcher` package publishes a `base_link->odom` `tf` and an equivalent message `geometry_msgs/Pose2D` expressed in `odom` frame. As `laser_scan_matcher`'s outcome is of a [cumulative nature](http://answers.ros.org/question/3231/whether-pose-values-returned-by-laser_scan_matcher), I'm guessing twist (velocity) information is calculated internally as first. So maybe, with some tweaking, it would be possible to make it publish `nav_msgs/Odometry` expressed in `base_link`, too?

Or is there another way of solving this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12489/obtaining-nav_msgs/odometry-from-a-laser_scan-(eg.-with-laser_scan_matcher)/) by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1079 on 2011-12-30

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the scan matcher isn't measuring velocity directly, but it is computing the delta in the laser position, which you could combine with the time between laser scans to produce a rough estimate of velocity, subject to jitter in your laser frequency and any errors in the scan matching.

Since laser_scan_matcher doesn't publish stamped poses, you'll have to modify laser_scan_matcher directly to compute this output.

LaserScan has a timestamp in the message header that you can use to compute the time between scans.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2011-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) on 2012-01-30**:
awesome, thank you!

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2012-01-29**:
Here you are, hope it's the working version :). http://pastebin.com/Nd4ekeuj http://pastebin.com/WgBpiaqH

**Comment by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) on 2012-01-24**:
@tom: Could you publish your changes somewhere? I'd like to use it, too.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2012-01-04**:
Thanks, that's exactly what I did.

**Comment by [mpai227](https://answers.ros.org/users/23104/mpai227/) on 2015-07-08**:
just came upon this thread. @tom - your code was very helpful, thanks a lot!. There were a few bugs which I fixed and it worked fine. If someone needs the code do leave a message I will be happy to share!

**Comment by [lisayoung](https://answers.ros.org/users/23296/lisayoung/) on 2015-07-22**:
@mpai227 Can you share your code please? I want to get the odometry msg from laser_scan_matcher. Thank you!

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2015-09-21**:
@mpai227 Yes can you share it, that's for me a fondamental piece of code. It should be an optionnal param of laser_scan_matcher :)

**Comment by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) on 2016-07-09**:
@mpai227 Many thanks to your code!

**Comment by [femitof](https://answers.ros.org/users/39985/femitof/) on 2020-02-26**:
HI @mpai227 I tried using the code, but it throws these errors when i catkin_make:

laser_scan_matcher_node.cpp:(.text+0x1f9): undefined reference to `scan_tools::LaserScanMatcher::~LaserScanMatcher()' laser_scan_matcher_node.cpp:(.text+0x34c): undefined reference to` scan_tools::LaserScanMatcher::~LaserScanMatcher()'
laser_scan_matcher_node.cpp:(.text+0x374): undefined reference to `scan_tools::LaserScanMatcher::~LaserScanMatcher()' laser_scan_matcher_node.cpp:(.text+0x388): undefined reference to` scan_tools::LaserScanMatcher::~LaserScanMatcher()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scan_tools/laser_scan_matcher/CMakeFiles/laser_scan_matcher_node.dir/build.make:312: recipe for target '/home/femi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/laser_scan_matcher/laser_scan_matcher_node' failed

**Comment by [femitof](https://answers.ros.org/users/39985/femitof/) on 2020-02-26**:
@Tomson did the code work for you? If yes can you share please

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would write a wrapper node that uses the laser_scan_matcher nodelet to get the cumulative odom estimate, then calculate the Twist information and publish an `Odometry` msg.

I was going to suggest looking at [robot_pose_ekf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf), (since it's a Kalman Filter I assumed there would be calculated Velocities), but I realized  that the node only outputs a `Pose` msg and not a full `Odom` msg.

---

Originally posted by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) with karma: 682 on 2012-01-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1